# C++ Pointer Array Won't Accept More Values

Tags: c++, pointers

please, why this pointer array won't accept more than 5 values?

Doing excercises from Prata's C++ book, but got stuck on this.

```
//ex2_numrow -- showing entered numbers til zero is entered 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int num = 0; 
    int* entered = new int[1]; 

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> num;
        entered[n] = num;                       

        cout << "Your numbers: ";       
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            cout << entered[i] << " ";          
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
        n++;

    } while (num);
    delete[] entered;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `entered` is an array of 1 integer. You can't expect it to store more. You are causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `int* entered = new int[1];` gives you a pointer to an array of size *one!*

It is *very* unwise (i.e., undefined behaviour) to then try to write values outside of that array. The *best* case is that your code will crash before it causes any serious issues.

> As an aside, the set of use cases for raw pointers is fast dwindling in C++, you should generally be looking at smart pointers instead.

I say "generally" because, if your intent is to have a resizable array, even smart pointers won't help that much. What *will* help is a little thing I like to call `std::vector` :-) You should probably look into using that for your immediate purpose.

For example, this program accepts positive numbers, adding them to a vector, then printing them out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int num;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> num; // should probably check for errors in real code
        if (num >= 0) {
            numbers.push_back(num);
        }
    } while (num >= 0);

    std::cout << "You entered:";
    for (int num: numbers) {
        std::cout << ' ' << num;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thx, but how to define ponter array where I don't know how many values will user enter? 
the empty [] doesn't work.

Comment: @Stnly83, see the update. You *don't* do that. Instead, you use `vector` which gives you pretty much everything you seem to be after.

Comment: @Stnly83 when you do use `std::vector`, don't try to add elements like `vec[n] = num`. That's undefined too if vector doesn't have enough elements. Instead do this `vec.push_back(num)`.